# すぐ上のセル内を操作し、特定の文字列の数を増やしたい

Tags: excel, vba

やりたいことの詳細は下記の通りです

①セルAをアクティブにして、文字列を入力する
②セルAのすぐ下のセルを選択すると同時に、セルA内の、入力した文字列のうち、
　一個だけ入力した特定の文字列をReplace関数で２個にする
※下記のコードでは、自動で２個にしたい文字列を「正」に設定しました。

しかし下記のコードだと、何も反応しません。
kazのカウントはうまくいっていましたが、置き換えのところが駄目でした。

どなたかアドバイスを頂けないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim PrCell As String, i As Long, kaz As Long

  '以下では、アクティブになる一つ前(一つ上)のセル内の内容を操作する。
  PrCell = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0)       

  For i = 1 To Len(PrCell)

    'PrCell内の、２個にしたい文字をカウントする
    If Mid(PrCell, i, 1) = "正" Then kaz = kaz + 1     

  Next i

　　'文字のカウントの結果が１個だけでありかつ
    If kaz = 1 Then

   　　 'PrCellがアクティブでなくなったら
        If PrCell <> ActiveCell.Address Then       

           'PrCell内の１個の文字を２個に置き換える
            PrCell = Replace(PrCell, "正", "正正")      

        End If

    End If

PrCell = ActiveCell.Address

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

上記のコードでは`PrCell`を`String`型で宣言しているため、`ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0)`を代入する時点で`String`への変換が発生します。ですので`PrCell`に値を代入しても`ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0)`の値は変化しません。

ですので変数の型を`Range`に変更してください。この場合代入に`Set`ステートメントを使用するかどうかで挙動が変わりますので、以下のようになります。

```
Dim PrCell As Range, i As Long, kaz As Long
Set PrCell = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0)
```

なお最後の`PrCell = ActiveCell.Address`は不要だと思われます。